# iOS8 Safari's bug?

Tags: javascript, html, safari, ios8

guys!

We are developing a realy simple web page. 
But, touch events can't work in iOS8's Safari if we use iframe and web clip.

We don't know why.
Hear is our code.
And, we use web clip.

Even if we touch the div(id="hoge"), the alert doesn't appear.

Please help us...

・index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="hoge">ABC</div>
      <script>
        document.getElementById("hoge").addEventListener('touchstart', function() { alert('Touch');});
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

・frame.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <iframe src="./index.html"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to be a serious bug. I have the same issue here. Found no workaround by now. The only idea that came to my mind is capture the touch events on the iframe container div and then send messages to the iframe content. But frankly I am not a great programmer, so this remains only an idea. And I guess a quite complicated, too.

Comment: Joseph Pearson offered me some code of his workaround creating synthetic touch events which I would love to understand, but… Maybe someone around here likes it and can explain it a litte… https://gist.github.com/joseph/a405924fe7f56631a38c